# How to check if database table exists when the table has 0 rows?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datareader

EDIT: So sorry for wasting everyone's time, the code below shows that I've just forgotten the 'C' on C_TABLE, after correcting it works fine.

In the following code "exist" should == 1 if the table exists in the database. However, it is returning 0 for me, even though the table exists in the database. I am not sure why this is happening?

Thanks:

```
foreach (var row in calcSched)
            {
                var dif3 = new DataInterfaceFactory(DatabaseTypes.SqlServer, row.DatabaseName, row.ServerName);

                using (DataReader dr2 = dif3.GetDataReader())
                {
                    dr2.ExecuteReader("SELECT COUNT(1) AS TABLECOUNT2 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'C_TABLE'");
                    var exists = Convert.ToInt32(dr2["TABLECOUNT2"]);
                    CommandExecutor CE = dif3.GetCommandExecutor();

                    try
                    {
                        if (exists == 0)
                        {
                            string sql = "CREATE TABLE dbo.C_TABLE(COLUMN_UID INT, KIP INT, SD_DATE DATE, ST INT, CS_DATE DATE, CE_DATE DATE, SM CHAR(100), PRG CHAR(20)";
                            CE.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: could not create C_TABLE");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: "My understanding is that there needs to be at least one row for this to return 1" - I wouldn't have thought so, no; that should work for an empty table, as long as it exists; did you test this hypothesis? (I just did: it worked fine)

Comment: The `COUNT(..)` over an empty row set always exists and is 0 (well, obviously). `ExecuteScalar` is all you need.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yeah, but that uses exceptions as the "no, it doesn't exist" case - not usually a good idea, but... it'll work, I guess

Comment: @MarcGravell My bad, I assumed that that was the case because my code keeps returning 0 every time, even though the table exists in the database.

Comment: Why not check `select object_id('TableName')` ... it will let you know if table exists, no?

Comment: @Veljko89 it'll tell you that an *object* exists, but not that it is a table :) it could be ... anything

Comment: @MarcGravell: I mean `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE ...`, not `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POSSIBLYNONEXISTINGTABLE`. The latter is a bad idea not just because of the error handling, but because it will actually count rows. (That's no fun if your table has a few billion of them.)

Comment: are you absolutely sure you're running it on the right database? ultimately the SQL you've shown... works

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is? I understand we can ignore your misgivings about the sql but then if I read the rest of your question right, you're complaining that your code doesn't create the table when it already exists?

Comment: btw; you aren't correctly disposing the reader; since you are always expecting exactly one cell, it would thus be preferable to use `ExecuteScalar`. You also aren't checking what the exception *says*... it could be "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first*, for example... because you aren't correctly disposing your readers :) make sure you actually note what `ex.Message` says

Comment: @MarcGravell row.ServerName and row.DatabaseName are both correct when I hover over them (dif3). That is where it is checking for the right database?

Comment: Are you probing the right database? and right schema?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen sorry, being completely wrong through me off. I have edited the question. Because the table exists, it should be returning 1, not 0. At the moment, due to the fact that it is returning 0 and that it can't create the table because it already exists, it is throwing an error.

Comment: Is it throwing an error because of the mssing `)` in your create table statemet?

Comment: Slight detour...I notice you are checking the schema in your query. Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES for the schema is unreliable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 You should be looking at sys.tables and sys.schemas

Comment: @SeanLange, but when you show how to use sys.tables they downvote:)

Comment: @SeanLange that's a complex topic - INFORMATION_SCHEMA is the ANSI/ISO standard - they aren't *wrong*, they just don't include some vendor specific feature information things. In this case, querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA should be 100% fine

Comment: @MarcGravell the fact that in some cases it is ok and others not is a pretty solid argument for not using it. Kind of like not specifying the size of a varchar because in some situations it might be ok. Those views were implemented to attempt to be ANSI compliant and MS completely missed the boat. They are a mess in so many ways. I just avoid them and it seems I am not alone. https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views

Comment: If the code you posted is accurate, check what `DataReader` actually is and what `ExecuteReader` is supposed to do. It looks like this is not using ADO.NET standard classes but some custom layer, which could do all sorts of interesting things with your query -- it could wrap or mangle it in ways unknown to man. You could also simply be going to the wrong server or database, again based on some dynamic configuration we don't get to see here.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `ExecuteReader`, and then you're trying to access data in it without first doing a `dr2.Read()`.

Comment: good eyes! however, it may be pragmatic (see my comment on the question) to simply switch to `ExecuteScalar`, to avoid some other related problems

Answer (score -2):

This is MS SQL Server as I understand. You can directly query sys.tables. ie:

```
select case when exists ( select  *
                from    sys.tables
                where   [name] = 'YourTableName'
                        and is_ms_shipped = 0 )  then 1 else 0 end;
```

Also you could directly query with GetSchema on the connection. ie:

```
void Main()
{
  string strCon =
      @"server=.\sqlexpress;database=Northwind;Trusted_connection=yes";
  DataTable schemaInfo;    
  string[] restrictions = {"Northwind",null,null,"BASE TABLE"};

  using( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
  {
   con.Open();
   schemaInfo = con.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions );
   con.Close();
  }
  // schemaInfo datatable contains all tables
}
```

PS: You are misdirecting people as if it were the way to check for existence of a table in MS SQL Server, and thus causing some people to downvote the correct way.

Comment: not my downvote, but I *expect* that the reason it is downvoted is because the *specific query* isn't the problem here - the query already shown is fine; we can therefore reasonable presume that changing the query won't actually help

Comment: @MarcGravell, I am not changing the query. Simply showing the correct way to do it. Why he should try using the wrong way?

Comment: this way is no more "correct" than querying info-schemas; and yes, you changed the query completely

Comment: @MarcGravell, this is the correct way to do it. Like it or not. (Somebody above already provided a link) information_schema is not reliable.

Comment: I can see we're not going to agree on that, but: either works *just fine* here (it isn't as though we need extra columns that only exist in the tables, not the views); the query **is not the problem**, so proposing a different query is unhelpful. I would *definitely* say that using `GetSchema` is a bad idea, though - completely overkill for this scenario, plus that API is just **horrible** to work with, especially when we only want to know one very simple thing (existence)

Comment: @MarcGravell, OK we can agree to disagree. As shown here you are not even forced to do a query. GetSchema is a good idea but you can't see it, no problem.

Comment: Happy to agree to disagree over which table/view to query (personally I'm OK using the ANSI/ISO standard views in preference to the raw tables, since we don't care about any vendor-specific flags). `GetSchema` is an *ok-ish* idea when it perfectly fits what you want, which it *absolutely* doesn't here.